# Getting maximum and minimum latitude and longitude of view

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

How can I retrieve the maximum and minimum latitude and longitude of the current view using the arcGIS javascript API (4.x)?

I can get the center lat and lon by using:

`MapView.center.latitude` and `MapView.center.longitude`.

I can also get the height and width in pixels using:

`MapView.height` and `MapView.width`.

However, I can't convert the pixel size to a lat/lon as the MapView.resolution property is 0. The MapView.extent is also null.

I am asking as I would like to query a database and only get the entries with a latitude and longitude within the view to save having to draw every point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the [Extent](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-geometry-Extent.html) of the MapView, which contains its xmin, xmax, ymin, and ymax values.

To get the extent upon loading the MapView use:

`view.on("layerview-create", function() {
    console.log(view.extent.xmin);
    console.log(view.extent.xmax);
    console.log(view.extent.ymin);
    console.log(view.extent.ymax);
});`

Comment: Hi, I have tried using view.extent but when I output it via console.log(view.extent) it is null. It does work when I call this when the pointer moves e.g. `view.on("pointer-move", function(){console.log(view.extent)});` though. Is there anyway to access the extent as soon as the page loads?

Comment: Take a look at this [blog](https://odoe.net/blog/quick-tip-arcgis-api-4-js-stuff-ready/) that shows when things are ready using JavaScript 4.x